# Attempting to use uninitialized value in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

When I type the following codes:

```
x=tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print x.eval()
```

It reminds me of wrong information with "Attempting to use uninitialized value". However, when I modified the above codes as:

```
x=tf.Variable([1.0,2.0])
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
x.initializer.run()
print x.eval()
```

It works well! I think that `tf.initialize_all_variables()` has initialized for the tensorflow variable x. So I felt confused about it. Any ideas?

Comment: Neither of these code examples should work as written (unless you have constructed another session in an enclosing scope). In particular, `x.initializer.run()` and `x.eval()` should raise an error because there is no default session—you need to create a `tf.InteractiveSession` or wrap the code in a `with tf.Session():` block.

Comment: That's right. Now It's clear for me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [tf.initialize_all_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables):

> THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2017-03-02. Instructions for updating: Use tf.global_variables_initializer instead.

That may be the reason.

Comment: It's not the answer. I still use the older version of Tensorflow.  'tf.initialize_all_variables' can work well in my other code.

Comment: You are right, it shouldn't even run on 1.0, I tried it on r0.12, the first code runs correctly only if i give the eval the current session: 'print x.eval(session=sess)'

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much.